# Json data not displaying on html server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a micro controller that communicates between C and it's html server using json. I have two json files: status.json, and serial.json. status.json displays fine, but serial.json will not display for some reason?

I have confirmed that serial.json is displaying correctly on the html server so my issue will be from the javascript/JQuery/HTML code.

here is what /serialdata.json looks like

`{"serial":"XXSerialTestXX"}`

here is my jQuery/Javascript code

```
function getSerialData() {
    $.getJSON( "/serialdata.json", function( data ) {
        if(data.hasOwnProperty('serial') && data['serial'] != "") {
            $("#serial").text(data["serial"]);
        }
    })
}
```

here is my html code

```
<div id="Instructions">
    <h2>Follow These Intructions to set up your device</h2>
    <section>
        <body>follow these steps to set up your device!</body>
        <div id="serial"></div>
    </section>
</div>
```

if i change div id to to an id I set from status.json it works fine, but the serial id from serial.json does not work, does my code look fine?

Comment: Are you sure you actually call `getSerialData()`?

Comment: what do you mean by calling it? I have included the script in the HTML code I thought that is enough and it includes all functions? I confirmed the java script code is being loaded by my HTML. Thanks for fast response!

Comment: You actually can define a function without calling it.
What @YaakovAinspan wants to know is if you are actually running the function in your script by writing `getSerialData()` somewhere.

Comment: so no I am not calling the script anywhere I just have it defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your script is calling your `getSerialData()` method.

**With declaration**

```js
// Declare getSerialData()
function getSerialData() {
  $.getJSON('/serialdata.json', function(data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty('serial') && data['serial'] != "") {
      $('#serial').text(data['serial']);
    }
  });
}

// Call the function.
getSerialData();
```

**Without declaration**

If you don't need to call the function anywhere else, you can just omit the function declaration and write directly your code

```js
$.getJSON('/serialdata.json', function(data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty('serial') && data['serial'] != "") {
    $('#serial').text(data['serial']);
  }
});
```

Comment: worked thanks a bunch! I am new new javascript more of a embedded system guy.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the function on the `onReady` event of the document. This one line below the `getSerialData` function declaration should do.

`$(getSerialData)`